# How do I add XMP metadata to each page of an existing PDF using iTextSharp

Tags: pdf, itext

So far all the examples seem to involve adding metadata while creating a new Document. I want to take an existing PDF and add a GUID to each page's XMP using the stamper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common use of XMP in the context of PDF is when you add an XMP stream for the whole document that is referred to from the root dictionary of the PDF (aka the Catalog).

However, if you consult the PDF specification, you notice that XMP can be used in the context of many other objects inside a PDF, the page level being one of them. If you look at the spec, you will discover that `/Metadata` is an optional key in the page dictionary. It expects a reference to an XMP stream.

If you would use iText to create a PDF document from scratch, you wouldn't find a specific method to add this metadata, but you could use the generic `addPageDictEntry()` that is available in `PdfWriter`. You would pass `PdfName.METADATA` as key and a reference to a stream that is already added to the `PdfWriter` as value.

Your question isn't about creating a PDF from scratch, but about modifying an existing PDF. In that case, you also need the page dictionary. It is very easy to obtain these dictionaries:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
PdfDictionary page;
for (int p = 1; p <= n; p++) {
    page = reader.getPageN(p);
    // do stuff with the page dictionary
}
```

This snippet was taken fro the [`Rotate90Degrees`](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/stamper/Rotate90Degrees) example. In that example, we look at the `/Rotate` entry which is a number:

```
PdfNumber rotate = page.getAsNumber(PdfName.ROTATE);
```

You need to look for the `/Metadata` entry, which is a stream:

```
PRStream stream = (PRStream) page.getAsStream(PdfName.METADATA);
```

Maybe this stream is `null`, in this case, you need to add a `/Metadata` entry as is shown in the [AddXmpToPage](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/stamper/AddXmpToPage) example:

```
// We create some XMP bytes
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
XmpWriter xmp = new XmpWriter(baos, new PdfDictionary());
xmp.close();
// We add the XMP bytes to the writer
PdfIndirectObject ref = stamper.getWriter().addToBody(new PdfStream(baos.toByteArray()));
// We add a reference to the XMP bytes to the page dictionary
page.put(PdfName.METADATA, ref.getIndirectReference());
```

If there is an XMP stream, you want to keep it and add something to it.

This is how you get the XMP bytes:

```
byte[] xmpBytes = PdfReader.getStreamBytes(stream);
```

You perform your XML magic on these bytes, resulting a a new `byte[]` named newXmpBytes. You replace the original bytes with these new bytes like this:

```
stream.setData(newXmpBytes);
```

All these operations are done on the existing file that resides in the `PdfReader` object. You now have to persist the changes like this:

```
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
stamper.close();
reader.close();
```

Comment: thank you so much ( total lazy question I know ) but how do I add the metadata entry. It is not guaranteed that each page will in fact have the metadata entry. Thanks again

Comment: I'm updating my question.