# How to fill xmp to /Metadata entry of PDF pages

Tags: xml, pdf, itext, metadata, xmp

I am working on a project, which embeds metadata to each page of the existing PDF (PDF/A3 standard). I have xml files as much as number of pages, the program would embeds the corresponding xml file as metadata into the page.

So far, my program adds a /Metadata entry to each page using by iText 5, and I am also able to add a simple string or text into the metadata entry in each page, and it can be displayed under the PDF tree structure in Adobe Acrobat Pro. 
       Here is my code where adding /Metadata entry to the page:

```
        writer.addPageDictEntry(PdfName.METADATA, new PdfString("123"));
```

The problem so far is how to add xml to the /Metadata entry? My xml files are some simple tree structures, I have no idea that how to convert xml files into PdfObject. By iText developer sites, it says the /Metadata entry in each page should contains a reference of xmp, i have no idea that how to do that way. Should I embed every xml files together, and pass the reference of the part into each page's entry?

[This screenshot of acrobat pro shows what my program can do so far, click here to see the pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgyQl.png)

Answer (score 0):

The `addPageDictEntry()` method isn't what you need. You should try the `setPageXmpMetadata()` method. See the [API docs](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext5/5.5.10/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfWriter.html#setPageXmpMetadata-byte:A-).

That method accepts a `byte[]`. Make sure that `byte[]` contains correct XMP data. The method will do all the heavy lifting internally. That is: it will create a stream object that contains the XML, and it will add a reference from the page dictionary to that stream object. As you probably know, it is forbidden in PDF to use a PDF stream as a direct object.

If you want to do it *the hard way*, by creating the stream object yourself, getting the reference by adding it to the `PdfWriter`, and then use that reference as the value of an entry in the page dictionary, you might find inspiration in the answer to this question: [How do I add XMP metadata to each page of an existing PDF using iTextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28427100/how-do-i-add-xmp-metadata-to-each-page-of-an-existing-pdf-using-itextsharp) (or [this example](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/miscellaneous/adding-metadata#1080-addxmptopage.java)), but the short-cut method should be much easier to use.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! That would really help a lot!!! Right now, I figured out filling xmp into PDF pages. But there is a new problem I met, I tired to verify my PDF whether is true PDF/A or not by Adobe Acrobat CC. However, the software tells me that my PDF file is not true PDF/A-3A, the error message is "XMP property is predefined but is not used in accordance with the definition (XMP 2005)". THe error property exactly is "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/dc:title". I am confused about this, since I dont know how to fix this problem.

Comment: How can anyone answer to this question without seeing the PDF? I can only guess that you have a difference between the metadata in the `/Info` dictionary and the metadata in the XMP.

Comment: Hi Bruno, I have uploaded my test pdf file to this Dropbox link below. Please check this out, I have no idea how to pass PDF/A-2B validity check.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/wibx73w99utbmmp/Univ.Of.Arizona_Libraries_azu_acku_z3016_ray29_1349_merged.pdf?dl=0

Comment: I think you need a specialist. Have you considered purchasing an iText license and getting paid support?